# why doesn't swagger generator plugin add modifiers in the interfaces?

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui

I am trying to generate modifiers in my generated code but it is impossible, it doesn't generate it, I don't know if I should add something else in the yaml file

it's an example

```
@Operation(summary = "로그아웃", description = "", tags={  })
@ApiResponses(value = { 
    @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "success", content = @Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = InlineResponse201.class))),
    
    @ApiResponse(responseCode = "500", description = "server error", content = @Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = InlineResponse201.class))) })
@RequestMapping(value = "/auth/logout",
    produces = { "application/json" }, 
    method = RequestMethod.GET)
ResponseEntity<InlineResponse201> authLogoutGet();
```

My config in pom.xml

```
<configuration>
                            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/test.yaml</inputSpec>
                            <artifactId>contract-service</artifactId>
                            <output>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</output>
                            <language>spring</language>
                            <generateModels>true</generateModels>
                            <generateSupportingFiles>false</generateSupportingFiles>
                            <modelPackage>com.empresa.proyecto.model</modelPackage>
                            <apiPackage>com.empresa.proyecto.api</apiPackage>
                            <invokerPackage>com.empresa.proyecto</invokerPackage>
                            <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
                            <generateApiDocumentation>false</generateApiDocumentation>
                            <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>
                            <generateModelDocumentation>false</generateModelDocumentation>
                            <configOptions>
                                <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                                <skipDefaultInterface>true</skipDefaultInterface>
                                <sourceFolder>/</sourceFolder>
                                <library>spring-boot</library>
                                <dateLibrary>java17</dateLibrary>
                            </configOptions>
                        </configuration>
```

Comment: Which modifiers do you want added?

Comment: public or void , i know it's default but could i add any other?

Comment: Well, all methods in an interface are `public`, whether or not that modifier is present in the source code. The only exception to that is if the method is explicitly `private` (only available since Java 9 and is not helpful here). Why do you want `void` (which is a return type by the way)? That method has a non-`void` return type (i.e., `ResponseEntity<InlineResponse201>`).

Comment: well, that's true , but , i don't know why in other projects in github when you generate the soruce code it adds 'public' , am i doing anything wrong?

Comment: Are they using a different version of Swagger? When you look at their projects, is there a difference between their configuration and yours? And if their code is generated by a different tool, then maybe that tool just simply behaves slightly differently, and doesn't take into account that the method is for an interface. Because for an `interface`, there is no difference between `public void foo();` and `void foo();`.

Comment: but if it doesn't return anything it's generate like ResponseEntity<void> getUsers();

Comment: I don't know Swagger, but if it returns `ResponseEntity<Void>` then that seems like it returns a `ResponseEntity` with no "payload". It's somewhat like returning a `Future<Void>`. So, at least on the surface, such return types seem reasonable to me.

Comment: i find it https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/3889